# simple tape js test for redux saga failing with undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, redux-saga

I've written a few tape tests for my sagas but the most simple examples are consistently failing for the same reason. I have a one line saga:

```
export function* clearUser(){
    yield* put({type: 'CLEAR_USER'});
}
```

my tape test is equally simple:

```
test('clear user saga', (assert)=> {
    const gen = clearUser();
    assert.deepEqual(
        gen.next().value,
        put({type: 'CLEAR_USER'}),
        'clear user should pass to reducer to remove user from state'
    )

    assert.deepEqual(
        gen.next(),
        { done: true, value: undefined },
        'clear user saga should complete'
    )

    assert.end()
});
```

However, the first assertion fails and says the value is undefined:

```
  operator: deepEqual
  expected: |-
    { '@@redux-saga/IO': true, PUT: { action: { type: 'CLEAR_USER' }, channel: null } }
  actual: |-
    undefined
```

I've confirmed I'm importing the saga, and other tests are working, why does this simple test fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `yield` your `put` effect, not  delegate to another generator.

compare [yield*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) vs [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)